# Intergrating Angular part of MEAN js with JAX RS

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jax-rs, mean-stack

I have a MEAN js 3.2 application which I need to deploy along with JAX RS.

I have `index.server.view.html`, `layout.server.view.html` files in `/app/views` directory.

I'm not able to understand which will be my index.html file?

Can someone tell me what changes I need to make? Do I just paste the contents of public folder from MEAN to the webapp of JAX-RS?

Comment: JAX-RS is your API, and the MEAN stack your product right ?

Comment: By the way, MEAN is independant, it don't need JAX-RS to work ... In my opinion, It must run in two different server. Your node(express) server will request JAX-RS for data, that's all.

Comment: yes, but now the need is to discard the MEAN js stack. JAX-RS API will be talking to mongo. So now I need to make the angular app from MEAN stack to be extracted and integrated into JAX-RS webapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the angular part in MEANJS is in the folder `public/`.

You only have to create and serve an `index.html` file.

This file looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>

    <!-- General META -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

    <!-- Semantic META -->
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{keywords}}">
    <meta name="description" content="{{description}}">

    <!-- Facebook META -->
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="{{facebookAppId}}">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="{{title}}">
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{title}}">
    <meta property="og:description" content="{{description}}">
    <meta property="og:url" content="{{url}}">
    <meta property="og:image" content="/img/brand/logo.png">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">

    <!-- Twitter META -->
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="{{title}}">
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="{{description}}">
    <meta name="twitter:url" content="{{url}}">
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="/img/brand/logo.png">

    <!-- Fav Icon -->
    <link href="/modules/core/img/brand/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">

    <!--Application CSS Files-->


    <!-- HTML5 Shim -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body class="ng-cloak">
    <header data-ng-include="'/modules/core/views/header.client.view.html'" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse"></header>
    <section class="content">
        <section class="container">
            <section data-ui-view></section>
        </section>
    </section>

    <!--Embedding The User Object-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var user = {{ user | json | safe }};
    </script>

    <!--Application JavaScript Files-->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <section class="browsehappy jumbotron hide">
        <h1>Hello there!</h1>
        <p>You are using an old browser which we unfortunately do not support.</p>
        <p>Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">click here</a> to update your browser before using the website.</p>
        <p><a href="http://browsehappy.com" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Yes, upgrade my browser!</a></p>
    </section>
    <![endif]-->
</body>

</html>
```

Your real problem is that MEANJS handle all dependency with nodejs, and you have to handle this too with JAX-RS or with webpack etc ... as you prefer.

PS : don't forget to replace {{value}} by what you need ;)

Comment: I have the layout.server.view.html and index.server.view.html. I think I'll need to merge those. I was just confused with the `{{value}}` then realized they were all from my environment files.

Comment: Yes ;) and the merge of those files is not really hard ;)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "MEANJS handle all dependency with nodejs"? Because I have all the packages needed for angular in public/lib using bower

Comment: Yes but you have to add them all in the index.html like `<script src=... />`

Comment: So like I said in question, I'll have to paste the contents of public in the webapp of JAX-RS, right? And the index from the /app/views, replace {{values}} Am I right on this one?

Comment: Don't know how JAX-RS works as a webserver, but it sounds good.

Comment: Even I dont know, a colleague needs it. :P
Will definitely try it tomorrow. Thanks :)